# How to get hash of aliased attributtes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have following aliases on User model:

```
alias_attribute :firstName, :first_name
alias_attribute :lastName, :last_name
```

How can I get hash with aliases as the keys, for example:

```
user.alias_attributes
{ 
  firstName: "Joe",
  lastName: "Smith"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [`ActiveModel::AttributeMethods` source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.1.4/activemodel/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb#L70) (where `alias_attribute` comes from), you'll see:

```
included do
  class_attribute :attribute_aliases, :attribute_method_matchers, instance_writer: false
  self.attribute_aliases = {}
  #...
end
```

and then [later](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.1.4/activemodel/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb#L208):

```
def alias_attribute(new_name, old_name)
  self.attribute_aliases = attribute_aliases.merge(new_name.to_s => old_name.to_s)
  #...
end
```

so you could look at `User.attribute_aliases` to get the hash you're after.

Of course, this isn't part of the documented interface so it may or may not continue working; if you use this functionality in your app then you should include some tests for it in your test suite so that you'll at least know if it changes.